# Logging fail in Appengine

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, logging

I'm trying to do some importing to a DB in App Store 1.9.26, in python 2.7.9, and to do so,I would like to get some logging so I can inspect some variables and have a look on whjt is happening

```
import logging

[...]    

updateDueDate = '2016.3.15'
fmt ='%Y.%m.%d'
fechalinea = datetime.datetime.strptime(updateDueDate,fmt)
fecha_aviso = avisoDB.modificacion.due_date.strftime(fmt)
logging.error = ('Date Call= %s, Date DB= %s' %(fecha_aviso, fechalinea))
```

Which should be pretty straightforward, but its not working. I think I mess up my python instalation or something that has nothing to do with my code, since the output I get from the devserver is:

```
TypeError("'str' object is not callable",)
TypeError("'str' object is not callable",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher 2.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher 2.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
INFO     2015-11-22 16:44:48,554 module.py:809] default: "POST /admin/filemanager HTTP/1.1" 500 -
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher 2.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher 2.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 272, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher 2.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/request_rewriter.py", line 314, in _rewriter_middleware
    response_body = iter(application(environ, wrapped_start_response))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher 2.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/request_handler.py", line 154, in __call__
    response = self.handle_normal_request(environ)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher 2.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/request_handler.py", line 184, in handle_normal_request
    self._PYTHON_LIB_DIR)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher 2.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/runtime.py", line 152, in HandleRequest
    error)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher 2.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 329, in HandleRequest
    return WsgiRequest(environ, handler_name, url, post_data, error).Handle()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher 2.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 279, in Handle
    logging.exception('')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1609, in exception
    error(msg, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher 2.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher 2.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher 2.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher 2.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 272, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher 2.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/request_rewriter.py", line 314, in _rewriter_middleware
    response_body = iter(application(environ, wrapped_start_response))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher 2.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/request_handler.py", line 154, in __call__
    response = self.handle_normal_request(environ)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher 2.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/request_handler.py", line 184, in handle_normal_request
    self._PYTHON_LIB_DIR)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher 2.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/runtime.py", line 152, in HandleRequest
    error)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher 2.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 329, in HandleRequest
    return WsgiRequest(environ, handler_name, url, post_data, error).Handle()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher 2.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 279, in Handle
    logging.exception('')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1609, in exception
    error(msg, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
INFO     2015-11-22 16:44:48,647 module.py:809] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 15086
```

Tried to upgrade python and GAE launcher, google for this problem, but with all the different options I get the same errors, and I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with my code, but... any one has any idea on what is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`logging.error =` *assigns* the right-hand-side (in your case, a string) to attribute `error` of module `logging`, replacing its previous value (which was a function).

When any Python code (yours or in the SDK) later **calls** `logging.error` (which you've set to a string), of course it will produce `TypeError("'str' object is not callable",)`!

> I think I mess up my python instalation

Yes you did, by *assigning* a string to `logging.error`.

> or something that has nothing to do with my code

It has everything to do with your code -- it's your code that does the mistaken assigning!

Comment: need to get some sleep....been reading the same error for over three hours without noticing the '=' sign.

Anyhow, thanks

Comment: @unaiherran, happens to us all, *especially* if we skimp on sleep (always a temptation!). Go rest, and, always glad to help!